# Sencha Touch - NestedList inside a NavigationView

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, toolbar

My whole application is inside a `NavigationView` which handles navigation between different screens.
In the main screen I have a button that opens a `NestedList` (always inside the NavigationView)

[image: NestedList inside NavigationView]

How can I remove the **NestedList Toolbar**, and be able to handle navigation with the main **NavigationView Toolbar** instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make navigation view's back button behave like nested list's back button, you need to override navigation view's back button tap event. To do this follow my answer on similar question , [How to override back button on Navigation View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860869/1211980) .

Once you're done with this, you need to identify each time, which view is currently displayed. If it's a normal view other than nested list you can simple pop that view.

But if it's a nested list then -

1. you'd have to find it's level. I mean on which level you are right now.
2. Find it's parent item from list.
3. load that view.

But doing all these will require lot of efforts and consume time. Instead you can place nested list's [toolbar config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-cfg-toolbar) at bottom with and two separate back buttons at different places. Nested list's back button will always consume `text` or `displayField` config as text applied to it and `back` button of navigation view will have some other text.

I've made fiddle to show how it'd look. If possible, you may want to consider this too. [see demo fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#3e2It)

**UPDATE**

If you still want to go for what you've mentioned in question. Here's another way..

Don't push nested list view inside navigation view. Use nested list itself and try to add **Back** button and other buttons to toolbar at top at first level only. Then after going deep, you'll get **back** button automatically. And from first level, write custom handler that will pop nested list ie current view and will load previous view. If you want I'll try to help you out with this in my spare time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply ! Adding a second toolbar at the bottom might not be the perfect way to handle this situation as it is a bit confusing to the user, but I'll definitely stick with overriding the back button method. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @Mehdiway check my answer update for some more info. You might find it useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, but I don't think that would be necessary, I ended up using a simple list containing the parent elements, and when you tap on an item, I push a new view into the NavigationView containing another list of the child elements specific to the parent. I guess that's the easiest way to do this. Thanks again :)

Comment: Pretty much all the ways in which the requested thing can be achieved, aye? :)

Comment: @EralpB .. I guess so. Didn't gave it much thought after answering the question first time. But I guess what Mehdiway did was much simpler if you want exactly same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
yourNestedList.getToolbar().hide();
```

for example in the `onShow()` of your nestedlist/view.

In the docs you can see a list of methods you can use for a Nestedlist:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this as a config on your nestedlist:

```
useToolbar: false
```